# Estimating Probability for first appearance of HT before HH and HH before HT using Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider the case where a coin is tossed repeatedly, I win when HH appears for the first time and you win when HT appears for the first time.

I know that one of us will win when the first Head appears so we have a 50-50 chance of winning.

But I recently studied about Markov chain and wanted to know whether it will be applicable here and if it is, I want to know how you can use it calculate the probability who has more probability to win.
I'm new to Markov chains and please help me solve this question

Comment: The approach you sketch is a Markov chain approach.  You are ignoring all the $T's$ you throw before getting that first $H$.  That's because the initial Markov state goes back to itself every time you throw a $T$.  Once you've thrown an $H$ you are in a new state.  Now, whatever happens, the game ends on the next throw.

Comment: To add to @lulu’s comment, you’ll end up with a Markov chain with two absorbing states. The probabilities that you’re looking for are the corresponding absorption probabilities.